# D3.js - overlapped bar chart when using rangeBands()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to create a bar chart with D3.js using JSON data. It seems most of the tutorials use either tsv or csv formats, so i haven't been able to find a suitable answer for my problem.

**Problem:** I cannot display columns evenly spaced within the chart area using the d3 function rangeBands(...). Instead they appear stacked on top of each other.

**I have the following data set:**

```
var jsonData = [
    {"Aluno":"Daniel","Presencas":1,"Media":5,"Cadeira":"A"},
    {"Aluno":"Daniel","Presencas":2,"Media":4,"Cadeira":"B"},
    {"Aluno":"Daniel","Presencas":3,"Media":3,"Cadeira":"C"},
    {"Aluno":"Daniel","Presencas":4,"Media":2,"Cadeira":"D"},
    {"Aluno":"Daniel","Presencas":5,"Media":1,"Cadeira":"E"},
];
```

**...the following scales:**

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y0 = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 20]).range([height, 0]),
y1 = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([height, 0]);
```

**... and populate the chart the following way:**

```
bars = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(jsonData).enter();
x.domain([0, jsonData.length]);

    bars.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar1")
      .attr("x", function(d) { 
          return x(d.Cadeira); 
          })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand()/2)
      .attr("y", function(d) { 
          return y0(d.Presencas); 
          })
      .attr("height", function(d,i,j) { 
          return height - y0(d.Presencas); 
          });
```

**The result is a chart with overlapped columns as shown bellow:**
[image]

I realize (or at least i think i do) that the problem is that I'm applying the scale "x" to each individual data item in jsonData (and not the whole set) like so:

```
.attr("x", function(d) { 
              return x(d.Cadeira); 
              })
```

, and hence the columns cant get evenly spaced (because it only spaces 1 element at a time). Is this correct?

How can i correct this?

Thank you for your time.

**[Solved]**

Solved the problem by correctly adding the domain to "x" thanks to vraiment's answer.

```
x.domain(jsonData.map(function(d){return d.Cadeira;}));
```

Comment: Where are you setting the domain for the x scale

Comment: Setting the domain doesn't work either. In fact my question has a little mistake since the image shown resulted from a test by adding the domain to x like so: x.domain([0, jsonData.length]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are not initializing the xScale domain (correctly).
Something like

> > x.domain(["A","B","C","D","E"])

Comment: i tried using: x.domain([0, jsonData.length]); but the result is that shown in the image

Comment: Basically, in your example Cadeirra is the x values. According to your json, Cadeirra contains 5 possible values: A,B,C,D,E. Now, The domain of a scale is the possible inputs. In your case, the possible inputs is A,B,C,D, and E. So, by doing [0,jsonData.length], the scale expects there to be only 2 x values : 0, and 5. But, we know that you want there to be A,B,C,D,E